# Freemarker - XSLT equivalent of copy-of

Tags: xslt, namespaces, freemarker

I'm trying to simulate the copy-of function in XSLT where I want everything within a node outputted in the response.

Using this template

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"D": "http://milyn.codehaus.org/Smooks"} output_format="XML">
${Order.orderitem.@@markup}
```

Facing 2 issues here

1. The output i get transformed the <, > as well of the XML tags. I do need XML formatting to escape invalid characters like & etc.
2. How can i remove the namescapes that appears in every node

My response is

```
&lt;orderitem xmlns=&quot;http://milyn.codehaus.org/Smooks&quot;&gt;&lt;position&gt;1&lt;/position&gt;&lt;quantity&gt;1&lt;/quantity&gt;&lt;productid&gt;364&lt;/productid&gt;&lt;title&gt;The 40YearOld&lt;/title&gt;&lt;price&gt;29.98&lt;/price&gt;&lt;/orderitem&gt;&lt;orderitem xmlns=&quot;http://milyn.codehaus.org/Smooks&quot;&gt;&lt;position&gt;2&lt;/position&gt;&lt;quantity&gt;1&lt;/quantity&gt;&lt;productid&gt;299&lt;/productid&gt;&lt;title&gt;Pulp Fiction&lt;/title&gt;&lt;price&gt;29.99&lt;/price&gt;&lt;/orderitem&gt;
```

Input being

```
<Order xmlns="http://milyn.codehaus.org/Smooks" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
<header>
    <orderid>1</orderid>
    <statuscode>0</statuscode>
    <netamount>59.97</netamount>
    <totalamount>64.92</totalamount>
    <tax>4.95</tax>
    <date>Wed Nov 15 13:45:28 EST 2006</date>
</header>
<customerdetails>
    <username>user1</username>
    <name>
        <firstname>Harry</firstname>
        <lastname>Fletcher</lastname>
    </name>
    <state>South Dakota</state>
</customerdetails>
<orderitem>
    <position>1</position>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <productid>364</productid>
    <title>The 40YearOld</title>
    <price>29.98</price>
</orderitem>
<orderitem>
    <position>2</position>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <productid>299</productid>
    <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
</orderitem>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent auto-escaping: `${Order.orderitem.@@markup?no_esc}`. (Unfortunately XML wrapping way predates auto-escaping, so it has remained like so...)

Prevent repeated `xmlns`-es... you can't. The problem is that the `orderitem`-s has no common ancestor as far as `@@markup` can know, where a common `xmlns` could solve this, so it does the safest thing.